# How to get number of players in a lobby in CS:GO?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

How do I get the number of players in a lobby CS:GO through SteamApi (or by any other means)?
Is this possible? In the official documentation about this not a word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think steamapi is capable of this. The only lobby related thing you can do in development is a lobby link which is found from invite links.